# Does a real constant affect asymptotic equivalence?

Tags: asymptotics, constants

The Meissel_Mertens constant $M = 0.26149...$ is defined as follows:
$$ M := \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\sum_{{p \in \mathbb{P}} \atop {p \leq n}} \frac{1}{p}  - \ln(\ln n) \right)$$
Can we determine from that definition that
$$\sum_{{p \in \mathbb{P}} \atop {p \leq n}} \frac{1}{p}\sim\ln(\ln n)?$$

Comment: Yes. Have you tried to prove it? More generally, if $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ diverge to infinity but their difference is bounded then $f(n)\sim g(n)$. Indeed, $f(n)\sim g(n)$ is **equivalent** to $f(n)-g(n)=o(g(n))$.

Comment: Why did you use the small $o$ and not the big one?

Comment: Because it would have been wrong if I wrote the big one. (Do you know what little o means?) Hint: $$ \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{g(x)}+\frac{g(x)}{g(x)}. $$

Comment: Yes, but I thought $f\in o(g) := \lim_{x\rightarrow a}\cfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$. And I meant Omega. Isn't Omega definined as $f\in \Omega(g) := \lim_{x\rightarrow a}\sup\cfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} >  0$

Comment: I can't understand why it should tend to zero. Asymptotic equivalence tends to 1 or did I understand something wrong?

Comment: Yes, $f(x)\sim g(x)$ means $f(x)/g(x)\to1$ and $f(x)-g(x)=o(g(x))$ means $[f(x)-g(x)]/g(x)\to0$. What's the issue?

Comment: I'm really sorry, I mixed things up. I understand it now. Thank you for your patient!